# Can we show preloader image for every background image with supersized 3.2.7 version

Tags: supersized

I am using Supersized jquery plugin Version : 3.2.7, I am placing 40 images for background slideshow with autoplay option. But after slideshow of 3 or 4 images, it goes to next slide even if the next background image not loaded fully and sometime shows half of the image only.

is there any option to show preloader image for every background image.